# find k with joint pdf

Tags: probability, probability-theory, power-series

I need find constant k in the pdf $f(x,y)=ke^{-xy}, ~~~~~x>0, ~~~~~y=1,2,...,M,~~~~~ M>1$

I try solve $k\int_0^{\infty}\sum_{y=1}^M e^{-xy}dx$

but $\sum_{y=1}^M e^{-xy}=?$

Any idea please

Comment: $$k\sum_{y=1}^M\frac1y=1$$

Comment: yes, I do not know how k.

Comment: You do not know how to deduce $k$ from the identity in my comment?

Comment: sorry, my question is $\sum_{y=1}^M \frac{1}{y}=?$

Comment: You can call this sum the $M$th harmonic number $H_M$ if you like. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number